# Why we make retrofit request as interface

Tags: java, android, oop, retrofit, retrofit2

I searched stack overflow for the answer but never find one, I'm curious why we define endpoint, request method in short a request for the server in the form of interface, what is the benefit of defining request as interface

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think Interface is enough for annotation processing. To determine what kind of request Retrofit class should make.

Answer (score 2):

For the simply reason that defining an interface is more easy than implementing it.

Retrofit is dead-simple to use. It essentially lets you treat API calls as simple Java method calls

With Retrofit you *describe* the endpoint that you want to consume as a basic java interface and retrofit will build a type safe implementation of your interface at compile time.

[Here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client) you can find a very good guide to Retrofit 1.9 and 2 and [here](http://fragmentedpodcast.com/episodes/46/) there is a nice podcast that talks about Retrofit and OkHttp.

Comment: so its internal to retrofit that how it implementing and using it?

Comment: yes, it's internal to retrofit but you can change some behaviors, example which http client you want to use (apache httpclient, okhttp), which json converter (jakson, gson), etc, etc.

Comment: thank you for such a simple answer. I also was wondering this but glad to see it literally is DEAD simple.